# How to reload the WinBUGS computation results to bugs object again?

Tags: r, bugs

I have run a very long computation in WinBUGS (million iterations) using the R2WinBUGS package from within R:

```
bugs.object <- bugs(...)
```

but the R crashed. **How do I reload the bugs.object into R again without running winbugs again?** I tried this (I have 3 chains):

```
out <- read.bugs(paste("coda", 1:3, ".txt", sep = ""))
```

but the `out` data structure is completely different from the bugs object (as it is, it is unusable). I tried to convert it with `as.bugs.array`:

```
bugs.object <- as.bugs.array(out, model.file = "ttest.txt", n.iter = 1000000, n.burnin = 300000, n.thin = 2, program = "WinBUGS")
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: We only need one of these questions, no clue which site is the better location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323929/r2winbugs-how-to-reload-the-winbugs-computation-results-to-bugs-object-again

Comment: I would say stackoverflow is better.  This is a programming/technical question, not a stats question. (I don't have enough reputation here to vote to close.)

Comment: As indicated in the above comments, choose one SE site and don't cross-post. As this is merely a technical issue (about which I have doubt you get a working solution---if R crashed, you're likely to loose everything unless you write to disk from time to time), I'll suggest keeping it on SO.

Comment: I was not sure where to put it, so I put it to both SO and stats... seems to be relevant for both, as most of the R programmers use SO, but also statisticians could have the same problem...

Comment: OK, I prefer SO too. Tomas